# what are the risks of having bigger image sizes

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, crash, uiimageasset

I have an iOS project and it has many images and for different resolutions 
iPhone 1x,2x and 3x and iPad 1x,2x and 3x.

some of the images size are very big 1mb and I am worried this might affect app performance or app can get killed as it would eat more ram while running.

Can somebody shed some light on this topic please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in this but I will share my thoughts. If you're displaying many many images at the same screen, so you might have a problem if u don't use Tableview or collection view to get the advantage of reusing the cells so only the visible cells are allocated in memory.

Also make sure to profile your app and make it free or memory leaks and retain cycles so all ViewControllers are allocated properly once you dismiss them.

Otherwise, I think you're fine